# how to setData in CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ckeditor, ejs

Hi I'm using CKEDITOR 4 to get some texts from a form. I can get an display data using CKEDITOR without any problem. But when I try to edit the content I already insert I run into a problem. I cannot get my CKEDITOR display the previous text which I taken from the editor to edit.
Below is the code I tried when editing.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.20.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<form action="/rel/<%=project.id%>/<%=releasenote.id%>?_method=PUT" method="POST" >
     <!-- Title input-->
  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
     <input class="form-control" id="title" name="title" type="text" required />
     <label for="text">Title</label>
  </div>

     <!-- Description input-->
  <div class="mb-3">
     <textarea class="form-control h-25" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
     <label for="text"></label>
  </div>

<script>    
    CKEDITOR.replace('description').setData("<%=releasenote.title%>");  // this works fine and display the title in the editor
</script>
```

I tried below code

```
<script>    
    CKEDITOR.replace('description').setData("<%=releasenote.description%>");  // this doesn't work and my editor also disappears when i do this.
</script>
```

My requirement is i want to display this description taken from the previous editor in my new editor for further editing. Please can someone help me with this.
routes i used as below.

```
router.put('/rel/:p_id/:r_id', async (req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.body)
    const project = await Project.findById(req.params.p_id)
    let releasenote
    try {
        releasenote = await ReleaseNote.findById(req.params.r_id)
        releasenote.user = await req.user.id,
        releasenote.project = project.id,
        releasenote.title = req.body.title,
        releasenote.description = req.body.description,
        await releasenote.save()
        res.redirect(`/rel/${project.id}/${releasenote.id}`)
    } catch {
        if (releasenote == null){
            res.redirect(`/rel/${project.id}/${releasenote.id}`)
        } else {
            res.render('releasenotes/edit', { 
                project: project, 
                releasenote: releasenote,
                error: 'Error Updating Releasenote'  
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put your data in between textarea tags and initialise ckeditor like normally how you would do.

```
<textarea class="form-control h-25" id="description" name="description"><%=releasenote.description%></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this worked. and also found out below code works for me as well. 

CKEDITOR.replace('description').setData(`<%=releasenote.description%>`);

I think my description text had some " mark middle and that causes the error. so changing " mark into ` solved the issue